# Arc length of intersection of sphere and elliptic cylinder

Tags: calculus, curves, arc-length

> Describe the intersection of the sphere $$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$ and the cylinder $$x^2+2z^2=1$$ Find the total lenth of this intersection curve.

I parametized curve as $$x=cos(t)$$ $$z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin(t)$$
$$y^2=\frac{sin^2(t)}{2}$$
Applied formula and get
$$\int_0^{2\pi} 1dt$$
I found $2\pi$, but my teacher said it's $4\pi$. I suspect that because of y, since has 2 possible values positive and negative.
My teacher solved as follows:

> Since the path is an elliptic curve in the space we can divide curve in 8 octanes. Thus, $S =8\int_0^{\pi/2}1dt$
> $S=4\pi$

How can we say that the curve passes all octanes and it's length is exactly same as others? And what to do when it wasn't symetric about axes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct. The integral $\int_0^{2\pi}{1}{dt}$ only calculate the incoming intersection of the "squashed" cylinder on one side of the circle, but does not account for when it leaves on the other side.

> And what to do when it wasn't symetric about axes?

Note that as long the cylinder intersects the circle with, **its centre common** to the circle's centre, then the arc length will always $\int_0^{4\pi}{1}{dt}$.

However, if the intersection is not perfect to a common centre, I would suggest creating $2$, $2$D side profiles to understand how your intersection will look.

Ie. for your equations, on the XZ plane:

[image: XZ-plane]

and the YZ plane:

[image: YZ-plane]

Comment: I don't understand what I am supposed to notice from xz-yz planes. Can I think of y=sint and y=-sint as "2" different functions, and their sum gives total length? But for different functions, if they intersect as some kind of line this sum would be greater than the actual value isn't it?

Comment: Yes parametricizing is one method. Have a look at this [website](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/arc-length-of-curves-in-three-dimensional-space-examples-2).